# Transforming XML to a CSV with some filter

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML that I am trying to transform to convert it to a CSV with some filter on. The header of my CSV is under  and only the header values should appear in the data below. All of this is working with my XSLT. However, I have a filter on a field where when the field name is "StdHoursFreq" and its value is "W" then Weekly should appear in the data. But for some reason it is transforming for all the Fields which has a value of "W". XML version is 1.0

Here is the XML with 1 data row to keep it simple

```
<root>
  <headerFieldsMap>
    <BusinessUnit>Business Unit Code</BusinessUnit>
    <CompanyName>Business Unit Desct</CompanyName>
    <DeptDescr>Department Description</DeptDescr>
    <DeptId>Department</DeptId>
    <DescrShort>Posting Job Title</DescrShort>
    <Description>Working Position Description</Description>
    <JobFamily>Category</JobFamily>
    <PositionNbr>Position-Nbr</PositionNbr>
    <StdHoursFreq>Standard hours Frequency</StdHoursFreq>
    <TotalWorkingHours>Standard Hours</TotalWorkingHours>
    <PayFrequency>Pay</PayFrequency>
  </headerFieldsMap>
  <psPositions>
    <position>
      <PayFrequency>W</PayFrequency>
      <LocationPostal>10520</LocationPostal>
      <ConfidentialFlag>N</ConfidentialFlag>
      <DeptDescr>Structures H&amp;H Facilities</DeptDescr>
      <Description>Plumber - Structures</Description>
      <RegTemp>R</RegTemp>
      <SalAdminPlan>SMWI</SalAdminPlan>
      <JobCodeSetid>SHARE</JobCodeSetid>
      <LocationCountry>US</LocationCountry>
      <Remote>N</Remote>
      <Step>0</Step>
      <SalaryRangeTo>0</SalaryRangeTo>
      <PositionNbr>01000000</PositionNbr>
      <SalaryRangeFrom>0</SalaryRangeFrom>
      <EffStatus>A</EffStatus>
      <FullPartTime>F</FullPartTime>
      <PositionStatus>Approved</PositionStatus>
      <LocationSetId>SHARE</LocationSetId>
      <CompanyName>Metro-North Railroad</CompanyName>
      <RemainingHeadCount>-4</RemainingHeadCount>
      <PayFrequency>H</PayFrequency>
      <JobCode>25580E</JobCode>
      <RegRegion>USA</RegRegion>
      <Shift>1</Shift>
      <ReportsToPos>01005484</ReportsToPos>
      <DeptIdSetId>MNCRR</DeptIdSetId>
      <TotalWorkingHours>40</TotalWorkingHours>
      <DescrShort>Plumber -</DescrShort>
      <StdHoursFreq>W</StdHoursFreq>
      <LocationCode>HARMON</LocationCode>
      <Effdt>2020-05-04</Effdt>
      <LocationDescr>Harmon</LocationDescr>
      <LocationCity>Croton-on-Hudson</LocationCity>
      <Grade>007</Grade>
      <JobFamily>Craft Jobs</JobFamily>
      <DeptId>59201</DeptId>
      <LastUpdDtTm>2020-05-04T20:24:38Z</LastUpdDtTm>
      <LocationRegion>NY</LocationRegion>
      <ReportsToEmail>beilert@mnr.org</ReportsToEmail>
      <PayCurrency>USD</PayCurrency>
      <MaxHeadCount>1</MaxHeadCount>
      <BusinessUnit>MNCR</BusinessUnit>
      <JobFamilyCode>CRFTJB</JobFamilyCode>
      <CompanyCode>MNR</CompanyCode>
      <CurrHeadCount>5</CurrHeadCount>
     </position>
    </psPositions>
</root>
```

and here is my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
               <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:req="http://peoplesoft.com/requestResponse"
                xmlns:csl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <!-- Header row -->
        <xsl:for-each select="headerFieldsMap/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>

        <!-- Data rows -->
         <xsl:for-each select="psPositions/position">
            <xsl:variable name="row" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="/root/headerFieldsMap/*">
                <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="local-name()"/>
                <xsl:variable name="fieldValue" select="."/>

                <!-- If the field value is StdHoursFreq and it's equal to "W", replace it with "Weekly" -->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$row/*[local-name()=$fieldName] = 'W' and $row/*[local-name()='StdHoursFreq']">
                        <xsl:text>Weekly</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$row/*[local-name()=$fieldName] = 'B' and $row/*[local-name()='StdHoursFreq']">
                        <xsl:text>Bi-Weekly</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$row/*[local-name()=$fieldName] = 'M' and $row/*[local-name()='StdHoursFreq']">
                        <xsl:text>Monthly</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$fieldName = 'DescrShort'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$row/*[local-name()='Description']"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$row/*[local-name()=$fieldName]"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is the output

```
Business Unit Code,Business Unit Desct,Department Description,Department,Posting Job Title,Working Position Description,Category,Position-Nbr,Standard hours Frequency,Standard Hours,Pay
MNCR,Metro-North Railroad,Structures H&H Facilities,59201,Plumber - Structures,Plumber - Structures,Craft Jobs,01000000,Weekly,40,Weekly
```

As you can see in the output it is returning the value of Pay or PayFrequency as Weekly too. It should only return the value of StdHoursFreq as Weekly. Why is it not mapping it correctly?

Comment: Expected CSV outcome should be 
Business Unit Code,Business Unit Desct,Department Description,Department,Posting Job Title,Working Position Description,Category,Position-Nbr,Standard hours Frequency,Standard Hours,Pay
MNCR,Metro-North Railroad,Structures H&H Facilities,59201,Plumber - Structures,Plumber - Structures,Craft Jobs,01000000,Weekly,40,W

Comment: Hazard a guess Bi-weekly requires an entity for the "hyphen" symbol !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is not clear why you need so many namespace declarations. Your input XML has none.

Your input XML has one XML element twice. It was causing the issue:

```
<PayFrequency>W</PayFrequency>
<PayFrequency>H</PayFrequency>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:req="http://peoplesoft.com/requestResponse"
                xmlns:csl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <!-- Header row -->
        <xsl:for-each select="headerFieldsMap/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>

        <!-- Data rows -->
        <xsl:for-each select="psPositions/position">
            <xsl:variable name="row" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="/root/headerFieldsMap/*">
                <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="local-name()"/>
                <xsl:variable name="fieldValue" select="($row/*[local-name()=$fieldName]/text())[1]"/>

                <!-- If the field value is StdHoursFreq and it's equal to "W", replace it with "Weekly" -->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$fieldValue = 'W' and $fieldName='StdHoursFreq'">
                        <xsl:text>Weekly</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$fieldValue = 'B' and $fieldName='StdHoursFreq'">
                        <xsl:text>Bi-Weekly</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$fieldValue = 'M' and $fieldName='StdHoursFreq'">
                        <xsl:text>Monthly</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$fieldName = 'DescrShort'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$row/*[local-name()='Description']"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$fieldValue"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;
            </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
Business Unit Code,Business Unit Desct,Department Description,Department,Posting Job Title,Working Position Description,Category,Position-Nbr,Standard hours Frequency,Standard Hours,Pay
MNCR,Metro-North Railroad,Structures H&H Facilities,59201,Plumber - Structures,Plumber - Structures,Craft Jobs,01000000,Weekly,40,W
```